# How to late initialize a socket in java?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

```
Socket soc = new Socket();
```

Now, I have to pass the soc handle to a function which initializes the socket with appropriate IP address and port number of the ServerSocket. How can I do it ?
I tried:

```
Socket soc;
//then a lambda which initializes like this :
soc = new Socket("ip", port_no);
```

But, the lambda has to have the soc to be final. So, the only option that I can see is to late initialize that socket handle in a function.

Comment: What are you asking? You can create your `new Socket()` (if you really want to), and `connect()` inside the method.

Comment: I tried that. It requires a SocketAddress instance. I went on to directly create its object but it is abstract. So, how should I continue ? How to use connect()?

Comment: You could use a `Supplier<Socket>` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the constructor that takes endpoint details (and attempts to connect immediately), you can always create an unconnected socket and `connect()` it later on, whether in another method or a lambda.

```
Socket sock = new Socket();
doSomething(sock);
...
public void doSomething(Socket sock) {
    sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("foo.com", 6667));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
The only way is to transform it into a final array like this :

```
final Socket[] soc = {null};

    new Thread(() -> {
        soc[0] = new Socket("ip", port_no);
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't really do anything *useful* though.

Comment: He just asked how to initialize socket(already defined) into a lambda expression, so I answered it))

Comment: I can see that. People here don't always really know how to explain themselves, so they ask questions that don't make sense. This answer, while technically correct, is quite useless.